# OpenCV buffer problem when using external trigger

Tags: python, opencv, triggers, camera, raspberry-pi4

I'm using OpenCV with USB camera on a Raspberry Pi4. I have activated an external trigger by RPI's GPIO pin. I wrote a short Python code to test the trigger and made sure it worked. Then I wrote another Python program to save a single image captured by the camera. Here is the code:

```
import time
import cv2
import smbus
from gpiozero import LED

TRIG_ADDR = 17

def setup_trigger_control_gpio(pin):
    trigger = LED(pin)
    return trigger

def setup_camera(frame_width, frame_height, fps):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_ANY)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame_width)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frame_height)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 1)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))   
    if cap.isOpened() is not True:
        print ("Cannot open camera. Exiting.")
        quit()
    else:
        return cap

trigger = setup_trigger_control_gpio(TRIG_ADDR)

cap = setup_camera(640, 480, 120)

trigger.on()
ret, frame = cap.read()
    
if ret:
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imwrite("images/frame.pgm", frame)
    trigger.off()

cap.release()
```

I set the buffersize to 1, since I'm using a trigger to capture the frame exactly when I need to. The program however gets stuck on the `cap.read()` line as if it did not receive the trigger. When I ran the program after that I ran the short program for the trigger only, it has finished successfully. Sometimes I had to run the trigger program more than once for the main program to finish, which I find a bit scary, because of the inconsistency.

I tried to set the buffersize to 10, which seemingly worked, however the saved image was empty(all black). I have also tried to "flush" the buffer by reading the first 10 empty frames, which worked and I have finally saved a proper image. The real problems occur when I try to process real time video this way, as even after flushing the buffer, the images do not correspond to the point in time when they should've been taken. Therefor I would love to use the feature of setting the buffersize to one, so that I would know exactly which frame is being processed. I will be thankful for any ideas.

Comment: could you use a constantly running capturing (while true: cap.read()) and on IO trigger just return the latest captured image? Buffers are a real problem for opencv and gstreamer at least. Some cameras even need to be fetched for every frame. e.g. if it delivers data by h.264 stream.

Comment: I'm actually trying to do just that - and it works when I set the buffer size to a greater number, like 10. If it is set to 1, so that I can process only the image I need, the camera seems to be ignoring the triggers and so the program freezes on cap.read() line. When I set the buffer to 10, the program doesn't get stuck, however, the first 10 read images are empty. I figured it has to do with the buffer being empty, but I don't get why the cap.read() line returns an empty image, when I activated the trigger just before it. It could have to do with circular buffers returning the oldest data..